# parse.com sorting with milliseconds?

Tags: parse-platform

Parse Dashboard shows only minutes in createdAt column, but I need milliseconds.
Does [parse.com](http://parse.com) cares of milliseconds when saving object. So Is sorting by createdAt use milliseconds?

Comment: Almost certainly using posix via mongodb whose resolution is 1ms.  Not specified in the docs as far as i know.  Best thing to do would be to design a little test and post results here.

Comment: The answer is elementary. I took createdAt column. As I expect two objects with similar time (HH:mm) has differrent milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Sorting with createdAt in parse.com is done to the order of milliseconds.